# Native Nortel VPN on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, vpn

I've come across a guide for connecting to a Cisco VPN from a Mac without the Cisco client software:

> http://anders.com/guides/native-cisco-vpn-on-mac-os-x/

Would this also work with a Nortel VPN? Does Nortel use its own proprietary VPN or will one of the available VPN types work? (L2TP over IPSec / PPTP / Cisco IPSec)

Comment: Do you know anything about the particular Nortel product that is running the VPN? There are Nortel VPN routers that support a variety of standards-based protocols (L2TP, PPTP, IPSec, etc.)